# monit configuration | total cpu | syntax error |

Tags: linux, monit

Monit's [official documentation](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#system) states following:

```
# Test CPU usage including user, system and wait. Note that 
# multi-core systems can generate 100% per core
# so total CPU usage can be more than 100%
if cpu usage > 200% for 4 cycles then alert
```

But the above gives syntax error as:

```
/etc/monit/conf.d/test:61: Error: syntax error 'cpu'
```

Any pointers on same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have version of monit lower than 5.14, because this feature was added in this version:

> Version 5.14.0
>
> New: Simpler system-wide cpu usage test (total of user%, system%, wait%).
>   Example:
>
> `if cpu usage > 99% then alert`

Also, I draw your attention to the fact that from Version 5.16 total cpu usage on multi-core systems calculates as a number from 0 to 100, so your 200% value has no reason

> You can now check a process' CPU usage in a more natural way as a 
>   percentage between 0-100 on a multi-core system. For instance, to
>   check if a single-threaded application like node.js has gotten stuck
>   on 100% CPU,